Symfony 7 - Doctrine - Data Fixtures - Integrity constraint violation
I have a problem with getting sample data in my database.
There are three entities:

Books
BooksKind
BooksTarget

There is a OnToOne releationship from Books to BookKind and a ManyToMany relationship from Books to BooksTarget
There are also three Fixture-Files:

aTargetFixtures
bKindFistures
cBooksFixtures 
(I didn't know about DependentFixtureInterface, that's why the files have a, b, c).

If I execute symfony console doctrine:fixture:load I get the following error:

In ExceptionConverter.php line 62:
An exception occurred while executing a query: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '23' for key 'UNIQ_4A1B2A9230602CA9'
In Exception.php line 28:
> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '23' for key 'UNIQ_4A1B2A9230602CA9'
In Statement.php line 130:
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '23' for key 'UNIQ_4A1B2A9230602CA9'
doctrine:fixtures:load [--append] [--group GROUP] [--em EM] [--purger PURGER] [--purge-exclusions PURGE-EXCLUSIONS] [--purge-with-truncate]

I did some digging and realized, that everything works fine, if the cBooksFixture has only books with two targets.
As soon as I add a book with only one target, I get the error above.
Works:
$book1 = new Books();
        $book1->setTitle('Santa Claus\'s Story Time - 24 Magical Tales and Activities for Advent Nights: An activity advent calendar for kids aged 8 - 12');
        $book1->setShortDescription('Christmas is the most magical time of year, and with Santa Claus\'s Story Time - 24 Magical Tales and Activities for Advent Nights, your child will experience the joy of counting down to Christmas like never before!<br /><br />Each night in December, cozy up with your little one as they unlock a special surprise: 24 days filled with festive stories and fun activities. From whimsical coloring pages and playful word searches to delightful puzzles, every day is packed with excitement! It’s the perfect way to add a sprinkle of Christmas cheer to their holiday routine.');
        $book1->setPrice(650);
        $book1->setReleaseDate(new \DateTime('2024-09-13'));
        $book1->setAmazonLink('https://www.amazon.com/dp/B0DH4BHFNW');
        $book1->setCoverLink('https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/71PoNGy4J4L._SL1293_.jpg');
        $book1->setFeatured(false);
        $book1->addTarget($this->getReference('target'));
        $book1->addTarget($this->getReference('target2'));
        $book1->setKind($this->getReference('kind1'));
        $book1->setLang('en');
        $book1->setCurrency('us');
        $manager->persist($book1);

Does not work:
$book3 = new Books();
        $book3->setTitle('Zauberhafte Tierkinder - Entspannungskunst für Erwachsene: Ausmalbuch für Erwachsene mit interessanten Fakten, Malbuch, Geschenk zur Entspannung, Tierbabies');
        $book3->setShortDescription('Tauchen Sie ein in die zauberhafte Welt der Tierkinder! Das Buch Zauberhafte Tierkinder - Entspannungsbuch für Erwachsene entführt Sie mit 30 liebevoll gestalteten Illustrationen von Babytiere in eine Welt voller Entspannung und Kreativität.');
        $book3->setPrice(650);
        $book3->setReleaseDate(new \DateTime('2024-08-02'));
        $book3->setAmazonLink('https://www.amazon.de/dp/B0DC5K5JKN');
        $book3->setCoverLink('https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/71kxwKaygOL._SL1000_.jpg');
        $book3->setFeatured(true);
        $book3->addTarget($this->getReference('target1'));
        $book3->setKind($this->getReference('kind'));
        $book3->setLang('de');
        $book3->setCurrency('euro');
        $manager->persist($book3);

Is this because of the ManyToMany releationship? I am quite confused, because I thought I also can only have one releation between a book and the target using ManyToMany, e. g. Unicorn coloring book is only for target children, but Cute Animals is for the targets Teens and Adults.
What am I doing wrong?

I figured it out.
The problem is not the targetReferences but the kindReferences, since I made a OneToOne releationship between books and booksKind.
I was under the impression that this means one book can have one kind, but that's not the case.
After I changed the relationship to ManyToOne between books and bookskind, everything works now as it should.
